# AG-Grid - how to access params.api for other grid options before `onGridReady` is triggered?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using React.

I need access to `params.api` to create the required data for the `columnDefs`, but it seems the only way to access `params.api` is via a method passed to `onGridReady` - this is obviously too late. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Why do you need access to `params.api` to "create data" for `columnDefs`? Why is `onGridReady` "obviously too late"? In its current state, your question feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/155050).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `gridApi` to set `ColumnDefs`, you should set it with `AgGridReact` component's `columnDefs` attribute.

Reference: [Add ag-Grid to Your Project](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-getting-started/#add-ag-grid-to-your-project)

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            columnDefs: [
                {headerName: "Make", field: "make"},
                {headerName: "Model", field: "model"},
                {headerName: "Price", field: "price"}

            ],
            rowData: [
                {make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000},
                {make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000},
                {make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000}
            ]
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <div 
                  className="ag-theme-balham"
                  style={{ 
                    height: '500px', 
                    width: '600px' }} 
                    >
                    <AgGridReact
                        columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
                        rowData={this.state.rowData}>
                    </AgGridReact>
                </div>
            );
    }
}
```